# Jest: avoiding manual mock code duplication

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, microservices

Working with a microservice infrastructure.
Need to mock one of my imports from package-json, that points to a private npm module.

I have the module mocked in one of my repos, by creating a manual mock in the **mocks** directory, and that works fine.

But now, with all other repositories that use that module I will have to copy past the same mock into their **mocks** directory to ensure that jest uses the mocked version instead of the actual module code.

Is there any way for me to place the mock in the npm module itself and point each repo to the npm module's mock so that I don't have to duplicate a bunch of code across all of the repos that use that dependency?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide mock code right in the module. It [will not be](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks) loaded automatically as jest does with `__mocks__` in your sources' root directory but you still able to `import` that mock in your tests:

```
import mockedMyModule from "yourmodule/mock.js";

jest.mock("yourmodule/index.js", () => mockedMyModule);
```

or your can create `src/__mocks__/yourmodule.js` just to

```
import mockedMyModule from "yourmodule/mock.js";

export default mockedMyModule;
```

so automocking will work.